# Php/mysql search whith custom Dispaly

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

**I'm trying to make a simple search engine using php & mysql . I know how get mysql result using php. Its Work.**

ex : - Mysql database stored this  (database table filed "meta")

> I am having some difficulty with my PHP/MySQL search. It worked great
>   a year ago, but for some reason it has just stopped working. I have
>   tried searching and cannot figure it out. I have it echo my query but
>   it never adds in the WHERE clause. Any help is much appreciated. Form
>   Code: PHP Code:

Search word is  **searching**

**I Need to dispay search result like this**

> I have tried **searching** and cannot figure it out. I have it echo my
>   query but it never adds in the WHERE clause. Any help is much
>   appreciated. Form Code: PHP Code:

Comment: What code do you currently have which isn't working? Without seeing what you have, we can't help fix.

Comment: $result= mysql_query("SELECT meta FROM data WHERE  LIKE '%$keyword%' ");

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
$query= mysql_query("SELECT meta FROM data WHERE LIKE '%searching%' ");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  
if($count >0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

  
     echo "$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
        $count =1;

  }
  else{
  echo "<option value='' selected='selected'></option>";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
```

From the code above here, there's a couple of issues that stand out:

1. The echo for the option doesn't have an open for , so it's not going to show.
2. When you're echoing information from the $row variable, you're referencing id and name, but the query is only outputting meta.
3. The query isn't searching on a field for the where clause, and is therefore failing

The code, from what I can see, should be changed to the following to work (assuming no other surrounding issues):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT meta, id, name FROM data WHERE meta LIKE '%searching%'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($count > 0)
{
    while ($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
        $count = 1; // not sure why this needs to be here, but it's in your code so I'm keeping it there
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<option value='' selected='selected'></option>";
} 

mysqli_close($con);
```